# Unfamiliar Array line of code in doPost() method

Tags: java, arrays, servlets

The code below is a code from the doPost method of a servlet, it is incomplete though. As you can see it is the logic for getting parameters from a web page, that is the first and last name and date of birth. I do understand the getparameter() method, but in the 5th line, what kind of array representation is it? I am not used to seeing this kind of an Array method. what I am used to, or dealt with so far is.

```
type[] arrayName = new type[length];
```

and

```
type[] arrayName;
arrayName = new type[length]
```

in the 5th line. How come the array declaration equals to some dot operator and some method. Please explain or, if there is a label or Topic name, for this kind of an  Array representation, kindly let me know and I will qickly take a lesson.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        String firstName = request.getParameter("first-Name");
        System.out.println("Firstname:" + firstName);
        String lastname = request.getParameter("last-name");
        String dob_raw = request.getParameter("dob");
        String dobArray[] = dob_raw.split("\\/");
        String month = dobArray[0];
        String day = dobArray[1];
        String year = dobArray[2];
    }
```

youtube link to tutorial in case you want to refer
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7rSurdKrlk&index=14&list=PLTo_YL4Dk4Z_SxrG0XwbE1pGYyehh9gX3

Comment: Huh. I would actually expect that fourth line to be something like `String dob_raw = request.getParameter("dob");`

Comment: To Katana314, thats exactly what i was expecting, but the tutor here wants to output to the console month/date/year...hence i think chose the Array procedure. well here is the youtube link and its at 7:10   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e7rSurdKrlk&index=14&list=PLTo_YL4Dk4Z_SxrG0XwbE1pGYyehh9gX3

Comment: No, that part I understand. What's weird is that the code is retrieving the last-name parameter - same as the previous line.

Comment: Oops, very sorry, I typed it wrong.it should be actually  String dob_raw = request.getParameter("dob");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

String has a method on it called split() that returns an array and all we are doing is assigning that array to the variable dobArray.

Answer (score 1):

I assume we're talking about the line:

```
String dobArray[] = dob_raw.split("\\/");
```

[According to String javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>   This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

"\\/" is a regular expression string.  Consider that the regular expression is not really "\\/" but rather "\/" since \ in a java string escapes the character that supercedes it.  "\/" then is *again* escaped by the regular expression language, so really you're just left with "/" once you've factored out all the escaping taking place.  In short, divide the string into pieces, whose divisor matches a / character.  This would likely be handy for a string expressing a URI, possibly a file path, or in this case, a date.

I suppose if you want to know where you can learn more, [there is a straightforward tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) on regular expressions that you might find useful.

Comment: Note that the '\' character in regular expressions is also an escape character. So the regular expression \/ means : a literal /. Since in / is not a special character in regular expressions the escape is actually superfluous. so `.split("\\/")` will split on '/' only.

Comment: Actually my question is we usually declare and initialize or create an Array as one of these                            type[] arrayName = new type[length];

and

type[] arrayName;
arrayName = new type[length]  or type[] arrayName ={1,2,3,4}...but in the 5th line without creating the array or without giving it a length, how come we are assigning to = dob_raw.split("\\/");

Comment: @DigitalDave We're not creating the array, technically.  Split is creating the array and returning it, and we're simply taking the returned array and assigning it to variable `dobArray`.  However, if you were to take a look at how split is implemented, you'd see a line similar to `type arrayName = new type[length];`

Answer (score 0):

The String class method "split(String pattern)" declares the memory which is the actual array of Strings. You declare the type in String dobArray[] which is a handle to the array of Strings.

When you type
Object objectArray[] = new Object[3]; 
you have a handle, objectArray, to the array of objects initialized by 'new Object[3]'